# Pandas: reindex and interpolate non-contiguous data

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset arranged into 24 hour periods, and I'm trying to create a data-cleaning system that can deal with situations where the hour period might skip (say from 4am to 3pm with no missing lines between like this for instance:)

```
DET_SCN DATE HOUR MINUTE COUNT OCCUPANCY DET_FAULT CC_FAULT SUB_STAT
D11136 07/01/2014 0 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 1 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 2 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 3 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 4 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 15 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 16 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 17 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 18 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 19 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 20 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 21 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 22 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
D11136 07/01/2014 23 0 0 0 FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

I want the dataset to insert and fill the missing rows with NaNs
So far, after loading my data I've tried

```
dataIn = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')            
frame = DataFrame(dataIn)

print "Cleaning %s " % filename

siteRef = frame['DET_SCN'].str.extract('(D\d{4})').apply(Series,1).stack()
armRef = frame['DET_SCN'].str.extract('(\d{1}$)').apply(Series,1).stack()

armRef.index = armRef.index.droplevel(-1)
siteRef.index = siteRef.index.droplevel(-1)

#append column names
siteRef.name= 'SITE_REF'
armRef.name = 'ARM_REF'

print "printing siteRef"
print siteRef
print "printing armRef"
print armRef

#frame.join(siteRef,armRef columns['SITE_REF','ARM_REF'])
cleanframe = pd.concat([siteRef,armRef,frame], axis=1)             

cleanframe.set_index('HOUR').reindex_axis([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],axis=1).head()
cleanframe.HOUR = cleanframe.HOUR.interpolate('linear')
```

but that hasn't worked for me. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried looking at the other answers on stackoverflow but haven't found answers.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: cleanframe head looks like this

```
     0 CC_FAULT  COUNT DATE DET_FAULT DET_SCN  HOUR  MINUTE  OCCUPANCY  \
0  D1113      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN   
1  D1113      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN   
2  D1113      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN   
3  D1113      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN   
4  D1113      NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN   

  SUB_STAT  
0      NaN  
1      NaN  
2      NaN  
3      NaN  
4      NaN
```

And cleanframe info

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 37227 entries, 0 to 12408
Data columns (total 10 columns):
0            24818 non-null object
CC_FAULT     12409 non-null object
COUNT        12409 non-null float64
DATE         12409 non-null object
DET_FAULT    12409 non-null object
DET_SCN      12409 non-null object
HOUR         12409 non-null float64
MINUTE       12409 non-null float64
OCCUPANCY    12409 non-null float64
SUB_STAT     12409 non-null object
dtypes: float64(4), object(6)None
```

Comment: Could you post what `cleanframe.head()` looks like and also `cleanframe.info()`

Comment: Editted main body of question to include this.

Comment: It's a little puzzling your code, `siteRef.name= 'SITE_REF'` and ther other one does not do what you think, to rename a column call `rename`, what've you've done is add an attribute to that dataframe called `name`. Also the result of your concat is also strange, it's showing you having double the number of rows for `0` compared to the rest, I think you need to do some more debugging to see where you are going wrong, look at your code one operation at a time and print the shape and head at each stage until you are confident there are no errors

Comment: To explain: what I _thought_ I was doing at that point was splitting DET_SCN into two Series objects which I then named SITE_REF and ARM_REF and then I was concatinating those Series objects into the dataframe (and then deleting DET_SCN after the reindex) - I think the 0 results are because I copied cleanframe.head() and cleanframe.info() into the wrong place before I'd named the two Series objects :(

Comment: I think you need to go back and look at this step by step, at the moment there are too many things unknown and incorrect in order for this to be answered succinctly

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, the first thing I changed was the `axis` argument, it should be `axis=0` or removed as this is default.
I then reset the index and renamed it to restore the 'HOUR' column and performed the interlpolation:

```
In [37]:

df = df.set_index('HOUR').reindex_axis([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'HOUR'}, inplace=True)
df['HOUR'] = df.HOUR.interpolate('linear')
df
Out[37]:
    HOUR DET_SCN        DATE  MINUTE  COUNT  OCCUPANCY DET_FAULT CC_FAULT  \
0      0  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
1      1  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
2      2  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
3      3  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
4      4  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
5      5     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
6      6     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
7      7     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
8      8     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
9      9     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
10    10     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
11    11     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
12    12     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
13    13     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
14    14     NaN         NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN   
15    15  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
16    16  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
17    17  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
18    18  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
19    19  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
20    20  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
21    21  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
22    22  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   
23    23  D11136  07/01/2014       0      0          0     False     True   

   SUB_STAT  
0     False  
1     False  
2     False  
3     False  
4     False  
5       NaN  
6       NaN  
7       NaN  
8       NaN  
9       NaN  
10      NaN  
11      NaN  
12      NaN  
13      NaN  
14      NaN  
15    False  
16    False  
17    False  
18    False  
19    False  
20    False  
21    False  
22    False  
23    False
```

Comment: Hmm, now it's telling me it can't reindex on a duplicate axis?

Comment: can you show how your df looks like in your question, I imported your sample data without specifying any of the columns as the index and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm creating the dataframe like this: `cleanframe = pd.concat([siteRef,armRef,frame], axis=1)`

Comment: Edit the code into your question otherwise it will be hidden from others